# Music bot for discord with discord.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, typeerror, undefined

I'm developing a discord bot to play music in voice chat rooms. However, I have a problem with properties. When I launch the bot via "node main" I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadDefaults')". I'll leave you the link to my github with all the files I've already coded. I'm new to development in general so please bear with me. Every piece of advice will be taken into consideration.

Thanks a lot.

***Don't worry, the token will be reset before the bot goes live***.

https://github.com/DONOcoding/DonoMusic

I tried to define "loadDefaults" but without success.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

According to the package [discord-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-player), method is `loadDefault()` instead of `loadDefaults()`.

```js
const { Player } = require('discord-player');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ['GuildVoiceStates' /* Other intents */]
});
const player = new Player(client);

// Now, lets load all the default extractors.
await player.extractors.loadDefault();
```